# java method with a return array not working

Tags: java

Why is the following code:

```
    public class Example()
{
    float ar[] = new float[3];

    public float[] getExample(float sum, float sqrt, float num){
        ar[0] = sum;
        ar[1] = sqrt;
        ar[2] = num;
        return ar; 
    }

}
```

not working? I don't understand where I'm mistaken.
I have such a method inside an android project.
The editor points out "Return outside method".

Comment: "not working" can mean any number of things. Please add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined your class as if it is a method, you need to remove the () from the class name.
Change this:

```
public class Example()
```

to this:

```
public class Example
```

As the other answers have stated though, it's rather unusual for a getter method to be taking params and setting values on the property you're returning. A getter doesn't normally modify values you're returning.

Comment: No problem, it's a common mistake to make, and the compiler error messages are usually about other things as a result, rather than 'you have () on your class name' which would point out the error straight away.